# Let $(a_{n})$ be a sequence that does not converge in the wide-sense. Then it has at-least two different partial limits in the wide-sense

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Problem:** Let $ ( a_n )  $ be a sequence that does not converge in the wide-sense. Then it has at-least two different partial limits in the wide-sense.
**Proof:**
Let $ a $ be a partial limit of $ ( a_n ) $. Suppose $ a $ is real. From our assumption, $ a_n \nrightarrow a $ therefore there exists $ \epsilon>0$ such that for every $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ there exists $ n>N  $ s.t. $ | a_n - a| \geq \epsilon $. We can build a subsequence $ (a_{n_{k}}) $ of $ (a_n) $ s.t. for all $ k \in \mathbb{N} $ , $ | a_{n_k} - a| \geq \epsilon $. Let $ b $ be a partial limit in the wide sense of the sequence $ ( a_{n_k} ) $, therefore it is also a partial limit of $ (a_n) $. Then $ b \neq a $ since for all $ k \in \mathbb{N} $ , $ | a_{n_k} - a| \geq \epsilon $.
[ Another 2 proofs here for the cases where $ a = \pm\infty $ ]
**Note:**  I disregarded the other 2 proofs where $ a = \pm\infty $ since I had difficulty with the case where $ a $ is real. And " In the wide sense " means the limit is either a real number or $ \pm \infty $
**Questions ( About the case where $ a $ is real ) :**

1. To be sure, we essentially have in total 3 subsequences in the above proof? one whose limit is $ a $, second is $ ( a_{n_k} ) $, third is a subsequence of $ (a_{n_k} ) $ whose limit is $ b $ .
2. However , I don't fully understand why $ b \neq a $? My attempt was as follows:
   Denote $ (a_{n_{k_j}}) $ a subsequence of $ (a_{n_k} ) $ s.t. $ a_{n_{k_j}} \rightarrow b $. Then, since we already have introduced an $ \epsilon > 0 $ in the proof above, then there exists $ J\in \mathbb{N} $ for every $ j>J $ s.t. $ | a_{n_{k_j}} - b | < \epsilon $. Since also for all $ k \in \mathbb{N} $ , $ | a_{n_k} - a| \geq \epsilon $ then [ here I need to proceed but I got stuck ]

Comment: what is convergence in the wide sense?

Comment: It means the limit is either a real number or $ \pm \infty $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1.

We technically have three sub-sequences and a sub-sub-sequence. The sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sub-sequence of it self, the implicit sub-sequence $\left(a_{n_i}\right)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ which converges to the partial limit $a$, the sub-sequence $\left(a_{n_k}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ which was created in the process of the proof, and $\left(a_{n_{k_j}}\right)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ which converges to $b$.

#### 2.

You almost there in understanding why the sub-sequence $\left(a_{n_{k_j}}\right)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not converge to $a$.

A sequence, of real numbers, is really just a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ and a sub-sequence requires some strictly increasing function $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ where the sub-sequence is defined as the composition $f\circ g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$. So if we define $a_n=f(n)$, then we should define a sub-sequence as $a_{n_k}=f(g(k))$. If we add in another strictly increasing function, $h:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, then we should define a sub-sub-sequence as $a_{n_{k_j}}=f(g(h(j)))$.

We have that there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $|a_{n_k}-a|\geq\varepsilon$. We also have that $\{n_{k_j}:j\in\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq\{n_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$. This is seen from the fact that, using our example functions above, we would have $n_{k}=g(k)$ and $h(j)=k_j$ as well as $n_{k_j}=g(h(j))$. Since $h$ is strictly increasing, then it is injective, but it may not be surjective, so the image of $h$, denoted $h(\mathbb{N})$ is a sub-set of $\mathbb{N}$. Then $g(h(\mathbb{N}))\subseteq g(\mathbb{N})$. Using this fact, $|a_{n_{k_j}}-a|\geq\varepsilon$ for each $j\in\mathbb{N}$, since each $n_{k_j}$ is one of the $n_k$'s for which $|a_{n_k}-a|\geq\varepsilon$.

Alternatively, if you want to prove this result indirectly, you can define the following object:

Let $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Define the set
$$E=\{l\in\mathbb{R}:\exists\text{ a sub-sequence }\left(a_{n_k}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}:\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}a_{n_k}=l\}$$

$E$ is called the set of sub-sequential, or partial limits of $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

One can then show that $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to a real number if and only if $E$ is a singleton set containing a real number. In the case where $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ "converges" to $\pm\infty$, then this happens if and only if $E=\{\pm\infty\}$, respectively.

Comment: I knew there was a subtle point here, thanks. Just recently I have learned about cardinality of infinite sets and it sure helps to see the connection between the theory of infinite sets and subsequences.